# Selective repeat ARQ with C UDP sockets

Tags: c, winsock, repeat

I'm writing an app in C that uses WinSockets to transfer data from sender app to receiver app and I'm replacing stop-and-wait algorithm with selective repeat, where I now got stuck.

I understand that you need to send a window of packets and await acknowledgements for all of them afterwards, and move on to sending more packets after some has been acknowledged. The receiver sends ack message right after receiving a correct packet.

However I can't see how I should receive the acknowledgements on the sender side. Having recvfrom right after sending the packet would effectively change it back to stop-and-wait. Do you have any advice on how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea with a sliding window of packets. 
I propose you allow the receiver to ACK more than a single packet/sequence number.

That way the sender can keep several packets in transit with a finite maximum.
The sender doesn't have to stop-and-wait for each packet sent, but can continue to send up to the maximum amount of packets before having to wait.

If the receiver ACKs before the sender has reached the maximum, there will be no waiting :)

EDIT:

This guy has some nice ideas accompanied with code: http://gafferongames.com/tags/networking